# Why isn't there a SelectedNodeChanged event for Windows.Forms.TreeView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

The System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView class offers this event, but the Forms version of TreeView doesn't. What's the equivalent in the Forms world? I'm using AfterSelect but it doesn't seem quite right. Maybe it is in fact what I'm looking for but the documentation is a bit hazy.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There's none in WinForms TreeView. To quote MSDN for [TreeView.AfterSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterselect.aspx):

> This event does not occur when the node is unselected. To detect this occurrence, handle the Control.MouseUp event and test the TreeNode.IsSelected property.

Yes, this sucks.

Comment: Control.MouseUp? They must be kidding. What if the tree is being navigating with keys instead of the mouse?

Comment: Well, ok, it sucks, but you could always just extend the control and add the event yourself.

Comment: How can you deselect a node with the keyboard?

Comment: That won't deselect a node.  It'll unfocus the TreeView, but the selection will remain.

Comment: > How can you deselect a node with the keyboard?

Press an arrow key.

Comment: That will still raise the `AfterSelect` event by selecting another node.

Comment: Setting the `Sorted` property of the `TreeView` to `True` will deselect the `SelectedNode`. If you need this, you can put it in the constructor and not in the `Load` event, as it may unselect the node you have already selected programmatically beforehand.

Answer (score 10):

There's nothing wrong with using `AfterSelect`.

However, note that it won't fire if the selection is cleared (if `SelectedNode` becomes `null`)  Instead, you can handle `MouseUp`, as recommended in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterselect.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately when you handle `MouseUp` the tree view's `SelectedNode` property has not been updated yet.

Answer (score 3):

OK, this is an OOOLD question, but the problem really annoyed me.
I made this little helper class -- it works for me.

```
Public Class TreeViewSelectedNodeChangeEventHandler
Public Event SelectedTreeNodeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

Private m_selectedNode As TreeNode
Private WithEvents m_tvw As TreeView

Public Shared Function FromTree(tree As TreeView) As TreeViewSelectedNodeChangeEventHandler
    If Not IsNothing(tree) Then
        Return New TreeViewSelectedNodeChangeEventHandler(tree)
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function

''' <summary>Assigns 'Value' to 'this' and returns 'Value'.</summary>
Private Function InLineAssign(Of V)(ByRef this As V, value As V) As V
    Dim ret = value
    this = value
    Return ret
End Function
```

May add other triggers, e.g. Control.Enter, MouseUp etc. etc.

```
Private Sub keyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles m_tvw.KeyUp
    If Not Me.m_selectedNode Is InLineAssign(Me.m_selectedNode, m_tvw.SelectedNode)
```

Then

```
    RaiseEvent SelectedTreeNodeChanged(m_tvw, EventArgs.Empty)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub New(tv As TreeView)
        m_tvw = tv
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This could be in C#... :)

Comment: @Pedro77 - You could also translate it if you want to use it  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There's none in WinForms TreeView. To quote MSDN for TreeView.AfterSelect:

> This event does not occur when the node is unselected. To detect this occurrence, handle the Control.MouseUp event and test the TreeNode.IsSelected property.

You'd better use TreeView.NodeMouseClick event combined with AfterSelect. AfterSelect isn't called when you select the previously selected SelectedNode. So just call AfterSelect when necessary, e.Node helps you.

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node == tv.SelectedNode)
            treeView1_AfterSelect(sender, null);
    }
```