# How to add SelectedNodeChanged event to winform treeview?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

In have a `TreeView` in my `C#` application and I need a `SelectedNodeChanged` event in *winform* like the one in *[WebControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.selectednodechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)*

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671153/why-isnt-there-a-selectednodechanged-event-for-windows-forms-treeview) and its answers about using `Control.MouseUp` and `TreeView.AfterSelect` events, But its just not the right thing to do (*e.g the one OP mentions in that question*)

> Control.MouseUp? They must be kidding. What if the tree is being
>   navigating with keys instead of the mouse?

I tried to create my own `TreeView`, But I don't really know how to create a real event for `SelectedNodeChanged`.

```
public partial class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
    public MyTreeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //How to add event here?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this and you can use the `SelectedNodeChanged` Event

```
public partial class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
    public event TreeViewEventHandler SelectedNodeChanged;
    public MyTreeView()
    {
        this.AfterSelect += new TreeViewEventHandler(SelectNodeChangedEvent);
        this.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(MouseUpEvent);
    }
    void SelectNodeChangedEvent(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedNodeChangedTrigger(sender, e);
    }
    void MouseUpEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.SelectedNode == null)
            SelectedNodeChangedTrigger(sender, new TreeViewEventArgs(null));
    }
    void SelectedNodeChangedTrigger(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedNodeChanged != null)
            SelectedNodeChanged(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for posting the wrong solution. I've edited my answer.