# How can I detect if my selected child node is a specific child node?

Tags: c#, winforms, treenode

Since the TreeView control doesn't provide an event that is raised when a child node is selected on a tree node, I am trying to construct a way in which I can check if the selected child node is a specific child node. I need this to set a display based on the selected child node. It should look something like this:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
  TreeNodeCollection ParentNode = treeView1.Nodes;
  if (treeView1.SelectedNode == ParentNode.Node5) //If the selected node is child node 5
  {
    label3.Text = "This is the text for ChildNode5.";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered here:

[Why isn't there a selected node changed event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671153/why-isnt-there-a-selectednodechanged-event-for-windows-forms-treeview)

From the answer:

> This event does not occur when the node is unselected. To detect this
>   occurrence, handle the Control.MouseUp event and test the
>   TreeNode.IsSelected property.