# Event when leaving a node in TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have overridden the `TreeView` events `BeforeSelect` and `AfterSelect`. Both get called when clicking on a node in the tree. You can see in the code below that I'm outputting the name of the tree node in each method. Suppose the tree looks like so:

UpperNode1
--LowerNode1a
--LowerNode1b
UpperNode2
--LowerNode2a
--LowerNode2b

and suppose LowerNode1a is currently selected. When clicking then on LowerNode1b, eventArgs.Node.Name is "LowerNode1b" in both methods.
I was hoping that in the `BeforeSelect`, that `eventArgs.Node.Name` would be "LowerNode1a" because I wanted to do some work on that node upon leaving it.
How can I do this?

```
private void trv_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("trvApproval_BeforeSelect(): eventArgs.Node.Name: " + eventArgs.Node.Name);
}

private void trv_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("trvApproval_AfterSelect(): eventArgs.Node.Name: " + eventArgs.Node.Name);
}
```

Edit:
The `sender` parameter is a `TreeView` object. Unfortunately `SelectedNode` is null. Strangely, there is a member `prevHoveredNode` (which has a valid value even) but not a `prevSelectedNode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the incorrect events. Those events are meant to do things if a `TreeNode` is selected. With `BeforeSelect` you can indicate that you don't allow this selection, with `AfterSelect` you can decide what to do with the selected `TreeNode` once if has been selected.

However, you don't want to do anything with the selected `TreeNode`, you want to do something with the item that this selected `TreeNode` stands for. In fact, if it wasn't a TreeView, but another class in which you could select items, you'd want your code still to work.

Therefor, you need an event that is called when an Item is selected. Microsoft forgot that, and you'll see that they added it later in [System.Windows.Control.SelectedItemChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditemchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) See [also why isn't there a SelectedNodeChange for TreeView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671153/why-isnt-there-a-selectednodechanged-event-for-windows-forms-treeview)

Alas this doesn't help you. The neat thing would be to derive a class from TreeView, so you could use for other purposes in future. If you are sure you will only do this once, don't derive, do it in your destination class

```
class MyTreeView : System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
{
    public TreeNode SelectedNode {get; set;}

    protected override void OnAfterSelect(TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
         // raise event that previous node is DeSelected
         if (this.SelectedNode != null)
         {
             this.OnNodeDeselected(e.Action);
         }
         if (e.Node != null && e.Node.IsSelected)
         {
             this.OnNodeSelected(e);
         }
    }

    protected virtual void OnNodeDeselected(TreeViewAction action)
    {
         TreeViewEventArgs eventArgs = new TreeViewEventArgs(this.SelectedNode, action);
         // TODO: raise deselect event
         this.SelectedNode = null; // nothing selected anymore
    }

    protected virtual void OnNodeSelected(TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: raise event to indicate a node has been selected
        this.SelectedNode = e.Node
    }
}
```

Comment: On the `public TreeNode SelectedNode {get; set;}` I get the warning `... Hides inherited member 'TreeView.SelectedNode' Use the new keyword if hiding was intended`. It seems to work just fine as is. Would you recommend adding the `new` keyword?

Comment: No. Apparently a Treeview already has a property SelectedNode. Look up what it stands for. Does it have the value you were looking for? Does it have an event if if changes? If not, could you use OnNodeSelected to notify others that this already existing SelectedNode changed. Consider event OnSelectedNodeChanged

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the SelectedNode property of the TreeView inside the BeforeSelect event.

```
treeView1.BeforeSelect += (s, e) =>
{
    var selected = treeView1.SelectedNode;
    var next = e.Node;
};
```

if UpperNode1 was selected and you click LowerNode1a then UpperNode1 is `selected` and LowerNode1a is `next`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In trv_BeforeSelect(), I find that `SelectedNode` of the `TreeView` object is null.

Comment: That is normal of course, there is no active selection the first time the event is raised.